# SQL Query: Multiple select and sums on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure and I'm trying to select all the employees grouped by a manager with a sum of the employee hour type and total hours for a month.

```
[ID] - Int    
[ActualHours] - nvarchar(MAX)  
[TimeType] - nvarchar(MAX)  
[Cost] - nvarchar(MAX)  
[EmployeeName] - nvarchar(MAX)  
[SupervisorName] - nvarchar(MAX)  
[SupervisorNumber] - nvarchar(MAX)  
[Period] - nvarchar(MAX)  
[TaskName] -nvarchar(MAX)
```

A sample of the table data:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|  ID  | ActualHours |  TimeType   |    Cost    |   EmployeeName   | EmployeeID |  SupervisorName  | SupervisorID |    Period    |   TaskName    |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 8    |    7.5      |    Regular  |    18      |  Jones, Fred     |  42        |  Marks ,Thomas   |       54     |    Dec-17    |  Delivery     |
| 8    |    22.5     |    Regular  |    25      |  Smith, Bill     |  54        |  Doe ,John       |       12     |    Dec-17    |  Accounts     |
| 8    |    12.5     |    OT       |    22      |  Hinckly, Debra  |  66        |  Marks ,Thomas   |       54     |    Dec-17    |  Shipping     |
| 8    |    7.5      |    Regular  |    18      |  Jones, Fred     |  42        |  Marks ,Thomas   |       54     |    Dec-17    |  Returns      |
| 8    |    7.5      |    OT       |    27      |  Jones, Fred     |  42        |  Marks ,Thomas   |       54     |    Dec-17    |  Recievables  |
| 8    |    2.5      |    OT       |    27      |  Jones, Fred     |  42        |  Marks ,Thomas   |       54     |    Dec-17    |  Transfers    |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

What I'm trying to achieve is having the query return the following results:

```
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+
| SupervisorName |  EmployeeName  | TimeTypeRegular | TimeTypeOT | TotalHours | TaskCost | Period |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+
| Marks ,Thomas  | Jones, Fred    |              15 |        9.5 |       24.5 |      270 | Dec-17 |
| Doe ,John      | Smith, Bill    |            22.5 |          0 |       22.5 |    562.5 | Dec-17 |
| Marks ,Thomas  | Hinckly, Debra |               0 |       12.5 |       12.5 |      275 | Dec-17 |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+
```

I have tried the following but I'm not able to get both the sum of regular hours and OT hours and total sum in one query.

```
select SupervisorName, EmployeeName,  TimeType, SUM(convert(decimal(10,2),ActualHours)) As TotalHours, Period
from TableName
where TimeType = 'Regular' and Period = 'Dec-17'
group by EmployeeName, EmployeeID, SupervisorName
```

I'm using MS SQL Server 2017. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: How did you get `TaskCost` column? What's it logic?

Comment: I think you are missing EmployeeID from your table structure above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SupervisorName, 
    EmployeeName,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN TimeType = 'Regular' THEN convert(decimal(10,2),ActualHours) ELSE 0 END) AS TimeTypeRegular, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TimeType = 'OT' THEN convert(decimal(10,2),ActualHours) ELSE 0 END) AS TimeTypeRegular,
    SUM(convert(decimal(10,2),ActualHours)) totalHours,
    Period
FROM 
    TableName
GROUP BY 
    EmployeeName, EmployeeID, SupervisorName, Period
```

Removed period condition from where clause and added the same in group by clause -> Gives you the required result for all time period. If you want the result only for particular month, add period filter in where clause

Comment: Thanks, this worked after I had converted the Sum convert(decimal(10,2) as per Nik's answer.

Comment: Updated the query..Please confirm if it's working. :)

Comment: If RahulJain answer works, please select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement inside the aggregate function SUM to filter which rows are being summed:

```
select SupervisorName, EmployeeName,  TimeType, 
    SUM( CASE TimeType WHEN 'Regular' THEN convert(decimal(10,2),ActualHours) ELSE NULL END ) AS TimeTypeRegular,
    SUM( CASE TimeType WHEN 'OT' THEN convert(decimal(10,2),ActualHours) ELSE NULL END ) AS TimeTypeOT,
    SUM(convert(decimal(10,2),ActualHours)) As TotalHours, Period
from TableName
where TimeType = 'Regular' and Period = 'Dec-17'
group by EmployeeName, EmployeeID, SupervisorName
```